# Optional chaining working not as expected

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JS from one of Udemy courses where optional chaining is explained. I think I get it yet there is a strange outcome I cannot figure out. I'm literally starying at it for 30minutes and cannot see what is the issue here.

There is a `restaurant` object with methods:

```js
  order(starterIndex, mainIndex) {
    return [this.starterMenu[starterIndex], this.mainMenu[mainIndex]];
  },

  orderPizza(mainIngredient, ...otherIngredients) {
    console.log(`Ordered pizza with ${mainIngredient} and additional: ${otherIngredients}`)
  }
```

Then I use optional chaining on these methods :

```js
console.log(restaurant.orderPizza?.('salami') ?? 'Method does not exist 1');
console.log(restaurant.order?.(0, 1) ?? 'Method does not exist 2');
console.log(restaurant.order?.(0, 1) ?? 'Method does not exist 3');
console.log(restaurant.orderRisotto?.(0, 1) ?? 'Method does not exist 4');
```

And as a result I got:

```
Ordered pizza with salami and additional: 
Method does not exist 1
(2) ['Focaccia', 'Pasta']
(2) ['Focaccia', 'Pasta']
Method does not exist 4
```

Why `Method does not exist 1` is printed since method exists and is executed? There are no issues with `.order()` method tho, what am I missing here? Is it because of `return` and `.orderPizza()` is more like a `void`? But this concept does not apply to JavaScript right? At least it was not introduced to me so far.

Comment: Please include any code or text as text within the question, not screenshots of code.

Comment: `orderPizza` doesn't return anything so `restaurant.orderPizza?.('salami')` results in `undefined` and therefore triggers the fallback. You need to consider the entire expression on the left of `??`

Comment: Adding to the comment of @phuzi, [here is the reason why you shouldn't use images/screenshots of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @phuzi Edited post according to your guidelines. And thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because of return and .orderPizza() is more like a void?

Yes, that's exactly what's happening. Look at the following:

```js
const x = null;
console.log('value of x is ' + (x ?? '??'));

const y = undefined;
console.log('value of y is ' + (y ?? '??'));

const z = 0;
console.log('value of z is ' + (z ?? '??'));
```

Since  you don't return anything from `orderPizza()`, then when you call `orderPizza() ?? 'zzz'` it will process the right side of the `??`, as the left side is null/undefined.